# Can't change Background after switching to Unity on 17.10

Tags: unity, 17.10, gnome-shell, gsettings

I've decided to use Unity and after installing it I found out that the background image is no more interchangeable (is default Ubuntu). I remove gnome-shell and everything related to it (hopefully not too much!) and use now *lighdm* instead *gdm*. I can't even right click on the desktop. So far i tried to reset dconf and set an image via gsettings… none of them worked.
Any clue/solution?

PS. Meanwhile I resinstalled the gnome and selected it at login. there it works but not in unity.